# How to hide an item from Recycler View on a particular condition?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using Firebase Recycler Adapter (Firebase UI Library) to populate Recycler View. I want to hide an item(row) on a condition. 
I have a LinearLayout containing a recycler view.

I set linear layout visibility to Gone in `populateViewHolder()` method of recycler view adapter.

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, User user, int position) {

    if (user.getUserEmail().equals(Utils.decodeEmail(userEmail))) {
        viewHolder.llMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }

    viewHolder.tvUserEmail.setText(user.getUserEmail());
}
```

It hides the LinearLayout but the row remains there with empty space.

Is there any method I should override to overcome this or is there any way to achieve the result?

Comment: It would be better to populate data without not needed items

Comment: off-topic comment: also your `if` has no `else` ... it will you kick in the ass later(releted with view reusing)

Comment: I agree with Selvin, but maybe height=0 would do the trick

Comment: @Selvin Yes I will add the else part later.  But I am using Firebase Recycler Adapter so I am only providing a reference of node to it not any data. Is there anything I am missing to implement ?

Comment: Check my answer on this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156902/make-firebaserecycleradapter-get-data-under-conditions-and-not-all-of-them/46384299#46384299

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272566/5670752).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should hide all views or parent from UsersViewholder layout xml.
You should hide entire viewholder or each view

Entire viewholder:

```
itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or each element:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But don't forget to set them `VISIBLE` otherwise, you will end up with some strange things from recycling

Comment: This looks promising. I will definitely try this.

Comment: You can add a method in ViewHolder, like show() / hide() that handle all that work of visibility. Don't forget that is a recycler view, so you need to show view holder if condition is not met, otherwise will hide unwanted items.

Comment: Sorry to say, But, once the size of items increased, the problem occurs again and the blank spaces again appears. What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: Hide all items, including parents, cards. I had the same problem, but i resolved hinding all items.

Comment: I did as you suggested. But still problem seems to be exist. Here is my code. http://pastebin.com/8f4PAsh3

Comment: When i said all element, i reffer to your LinearLayout, Relative, TextView and ImageView, not itemview.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Your solution works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin - Sorry for bringing up the conversation again after 4 years... But how do you get the LinearLayout from the view holder?

Answer (score 199):

In some cases changing only visibility attribute might still end up as allocated blank space (because of parent view's padding, margins, inner elements etc). Then changing height of the parent view helps:

```
holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Then be sure that in the condition that it should be visible, also set:

```
holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You need to do that because the viewHolder is recycled as you scroll, if you change properties as this and never return them to their natural state, other elements will be already hidden in the event they reuse the same view.

Comment: Although it's working great for linear recyclerview but not removing vacant space in grid recyclerview

Comment: This worked, but I am using a grid recyclerview, and there is a blank cell or two in between.

Comment: Don't forget to return Visibility of the view back  to VISIBLE & LayoutParams to  it's initial state in opposite case.In my case:              holder.lin.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: this is perfect.

Comment: If you get a crash by doing this! Make sure you you try "params = itemView.getLayoutParams()" then set the width/height on that params object. After that: "itemView.setLayoutParams(params)".

Comment: That's so perfect!
but pay attention, the design for your RecyclerView will hide too when set the holder is visible.
to resolve this just delete line 2 in the last code.

Comment: Sometimes even after doing this I still got white spaces. So, for that I did `recyclerView.requestLayout()` after changing layoutparams and it worked fine.

Comment: @KoustuvGanguly you are welcome. I'm surprised to see that after 4 years this issue is still relevant :)

Answer (score 30):

## **IF**

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

> gives you a Blank view

Then follow This.

```
public static class Data_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final LinearLayout layout;
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

    public Show_Chat_ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        .
        .
        .
        layout =(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_item_layout);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        .
        .
        .
    }

    private void Layout_hide() {
        params.height = 0;
        //itemView.setLayoutParams(params); //This One.
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);   //Or This one.

    }
  }
```

Now Call from **Adapter**

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapte......{
public void populateViewHolder.....{

if(model.getData().equals("..Something.."))
  {
      viewHolder.Layout_hide();
  }
else
      viewHolder.Person_Email(model.getEmail());
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is better solution than `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. Because you don't have to clear margins and decorations of the `ViewHolder`.

Comment: All depending of your entire view. If you have a `LinearLayout` and use `GONE`, you view will retract fine.

Comment: i used `itemView.setLayoutParams(...)` and it worked beautifully for me. thanks!

Comment: Nice, however your java conventions seems odd by using snake_case and capital case methods

Answer (score 8):

If you are hiding whole itemView and facing the problem of blank spaces.

Try this to hide the itemView.

```
holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 0;
params.width = 0;
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And this to show it.

```
holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This is a recyclerView, so use both in if else block or you might encounter some unintended UI issues.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built in way to hide a child in RecyclerView.
But you can implement this feature in your Adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<...>{
    List<Object> items;
    Map<Integer,Object> deletedItems;
    ...

    public void hideItem(final int position) {
         deletedItems.add(position, items.get(position));
         items.remove(position);
         notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: But I haven't implemented custom RecyclerView Adapter. As I mentioned, I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Comment: This works only if your itemView is a data in an array, because it may be a header or other kind of element that you want to delete that will mess all around if you do this.

Answer (score 5):

"GONE" will not remove the space occupied by the item ....you can use

```
if (condition) {
         item.layoutParams.height = 0
         item.layoutParams.width = 0
}
```

inside "onBindViewHolder"

Comment: you should set the height and width back in else statement!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like RV internally caches root view info so changing it's visibility does nothing to occuppied space by the item.

Wrap you RV item view with FrameLayout and set View.GONE to inner view. This way occupped space will be cleared correctly as well as item won't be shown at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OfferViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewOfferName;
    public LabelImageView labelImageView;
    public TextView textViewOldPrice;
    public TextView textViewNewPrice;
    public TextView textViewShopName;
    public TextView textViewTimeDate;
    public TextView textViewDistance;

    public LinearLayout linearLayoutMain;


    public OfferViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        linearLayoutMain=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_main);
        textViewOfferName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewoffername);
        labelImageView=(LabelImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.labelImageView) ;
        textViewOldPrice=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewOldPrice);
        textViewNewPrice=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNewPrice);
        textViewShopName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopName);
        textViewTimeDate=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        textViewDistance=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDistance);

        linearLayoutMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewOfferName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        labelImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewOldPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewNewPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewShopName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewTimeDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewDistance.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    }


}`enter code here`
```

THEN IN YOUR ADAPTER

```
 if (a.equals(offer.getOfferCategory())) {


                        if (offer.getOfferCategory()==null){
//                            chatMessageViewHolder.getLinearLayoutMain().setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            chatMessageViewHolder.linearLayoutMain.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));


                        }
                        else {
                            chatMessageViewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.textViewShopName.setText(offer.getOfferCategory());
                            chatMessageViewHolder.linearLayoutMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.textViewOfferName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.labelImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.textViewOldPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.textViewNewPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.textViewShopName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.textViewTimeDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            chatMessageViewHolder.textViewDistance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
```

**Thank you lorescu George Cătălin and Dhalav**

Answer (score 0):

this code is not working now:

```java
holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I am using this:

```java
holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.card).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

you can easily send the `ViewHolder` value to your action function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend answers with setting height and width of View to 0 because adapter still needs to render them and if there are too many hidden items this can cause lags, it is better to change the list itself and then send it to the adapter

Comment: Please try to improve the other answers or provide a real answer instead of writing a answer that only is a comment to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun hideShowItemView(itemView: View, toShow: Boolean) {
        itemView.isVisible = toShow
        itemView.layoutParams.height = if (toShow) ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT else 0
 }
```

1. itemView is an ItemView of the ViewHolder
2. toShow is a boolean to hide or show item of recyclerview

Use below line of code in onBindViewHolder block as per the requirement,

```
To hide Item : hideShowItemView(holder.itemView, false)

To show Item : hideShowItemView(holder.itemView, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate empty spaces between items in the list, incorporate the following code within the `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter class:

```
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?