# Hide a Value from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter View

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, filtering, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm creating an app similar to Chat app.Now I don't want current user which account currently logged in the device to show in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter result list.I've current user UID. Now I want to filter only this current UID from Adapter.How can it possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Here is my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter code

```
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Donors, DonorsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Donors, DonorsViewHolder>(
            Donors.class,
            R.layout.donors_single_layout,
            DonorsViewHolder.class,
            mUsersDatabase.orderByChild("search").equalTo(searchKey)
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(DonorsViewHolder viewHolder, Donors model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setLocation(model.getLocation());
            viewHolder.setImage(model.getThumb_image(), getApplicationContext());
            viewHolder.setGroup(model.getGroup());

            final String donorID = getRef(position).getKey();

            //WANTED TO HIDE THIS WAY BUT THAT DOESN"T WORK :( 
            if(donorID == mCurrentUserId){
               viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                return;
            }

        }
    };

    mDonorsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: you want only hide or remove ?

Comment: I want to only hide sir. Do not need to remove the current user from database

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223413/how-to-hide-an-item-from-recycler-view-on-a-particular-condition

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
 viewHolder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Your **code** be like this:

```
if(donorID == mCurrentUserId){
               viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
               viewHolder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return;
            }
```

**Or**:

```
viewHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

So **code** be like this:

```
if(donorID == mCurrentUserId){
                   viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                   viewHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return;
                }
```

this if Works hides the **itemview**

Comment: sorry... .setVisibility(View.INIVISIBLE) isn't working for viewHolder.Thanks for your time

Comment: What happens when you add? @WalidAlAshik

Comment: Try my second way. @WalidAlAshik