# ArrayList returned is of size 0

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an arraylist in my adapter class. I add some items to it in `OnLongClick()` method . When I print its size using Log inside OnLongClick() method it prints size 1 on adding one item but if I print it inside another method `getList()` it prints size 0 on adding one item.

Adapter :

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private ArrayList<String> mData2;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int selected_position ;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private ArrayList<String> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.dell_1.myapp3.InternalMemory";
    private Context context;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data, ArrayList<String> data2) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        this.mData2 = data2;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {  //this is the method asked by user902383
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            selected_position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (mSelected.contains(Integer.toString(selected_position))) {
                mSelected.remove(Integer.toString(selected_position));
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);// remove item from list;
                // update view (v) state here
                // eg: remove highlight
            } else {
                mSelected.add(Integer.toString(selected_position));
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                // add item to list
                // update view (v) state here
                // eg: add highlight
            }
            Log.v(TAG, Integer.toString(mSelected.size()) + " this is size");  //this returns size 1
            return  true;
        }
    }

   protected  ArrayList<String>  getList(){
            Log.v(TAG,Integer.toString(mSelected.size()) + "  final size"); //this returns size 0
            return mSelected;

        }
```

LOG :

```
02-16 16:00:52.129 16797-16797/com.example.dell_1.Myapp3 V/com.example.dell_1.myapp3.InternalMemory: 0  final size
02-16 16:00:52.130 16797-16797/com.example.dell_1.Myapp3 V/com.example.dell_1.myapp3.InternalMemory: 1 this is size
```

Also, many people are saying I am removing the item after adding it, but `selected_position = getAdapterPosition();` **which means its value is different onLongClicking different items . I wrote this method to add items on selection and remove on deselection , so I am removing an item already added when I deselect it(Long click again the already selected item).**

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Put break points and check where the value is getting changed. 
If that doesn't check the current object reference whether it is the same or not. And please give a little more details.

Comment: can you paste more code how you initializing adapter instance.

Comment: can you post method with this line `Log.v(TAG, Integer.toString(mSelected.size())), it prints 1` ? i wonder do you have local instance of mSelected which has correct size, but array with you return is still empty

Comment: Try to instanciate  mSelected in the adapter's constructor and remove "= new ArrayList<>();" from its declaration

Comment: How will I set the adapter then ? mSelected is the arraylist containing selected items @Mohamed, I am not selecting any items on activity creation

Comment: Try to replace "private ArrayList<String> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();" with "private List<String> mSelected;" and in construcor method "public MyRecyclerViewAdapter" initialize the array "this.mSelected = new ArrayList<>();"

Comment: done that, it  doesn't change anything @Mohamed

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're removing the item from the list each item you're doing onLongClick():

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) { 

  if (mSelected.contains(Integer.toString(selected_position))) {
     mSelected.remove(Integer.toString(selected_position));
     ...
  } else {
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Instead of removing the item from the list, you can make the item view gone with:

```
itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Read more for the set view gone at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342024/4758255

Comment: it throws a null pointer exception on deselecting an item , also I remove item only when I longclick again, so it should get only added , not removed on longclicking once , shouldn't it ??