# How to hide a child item in a recyclerView based on a condition?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

First I used the following code but it did not show **Perishable** for items with the **Food** category.

```
            if(model.main_category=="Food"){
                holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.text="Perishable"
                
            }else{
                holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.visibility=View.GONE
            }
```

Then I used the following code and it showed "Perishable" for the first and the last item in the `recyclerView` where only the first item was under the 'Food' category, however, the last item in the `recyclerView` was not belong to 'Food' category. Then I changed the category of the item in the Firestore database from 'Food' to something else and the 'Perishable' is gone from both the first and last item in the `recyclerView` (where the last item is not food). With this code, items in between shows 'Perishable' correctly according to their category. What am I doing wrong here?

What I want is that it should show 'Perishable' for items belong to the 'Food' category and hide the view for other categories.

```
            if(model.main_category=="Food"){
                holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.text="Perishable"
                holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            }else{
//              holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is not the adapter's responsibility; construct your data beforehand, and then pass the correct list to the adapter with the data you want to show. The adapter shouldn't need to worry about things like this.

Comment: check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342024/12709358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the `visibility` of the views but not defining the else condition properly. Sometimes the recyclerview doesn't refresh views properly because of that ambiguity.

Try this:

```
    if(model.main_category == "Food") {
        holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.text = "Perishable"
    } else {
        holder.itemView.tv_dashboard_item_type.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

As Yash Joshi said, you have to define the condition in full
Because the items are not recreated again, the same item changes its values according to your definition. If the full condition is not defined, the previous values remain on that item